# Быстрый поиск: выдача поисковых фраз по первым буквам

Tags: javascript, json, google-search

Подскажите, пожалуйста, `Google API` по выдаче вариантов поисковых фраз, когда вводишь первые буквы в окно поисковика.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Теперь разбирайтесь с [Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview). [Google Ajax Search API](https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/?hl=en) уже больше не существует.

UPD: вот [инструмент](http://blog.shreyaschand.com/2013/01/03/google-autocomplete-api/) попроще. До сих пор работает, только что проверил.

Comment: Что-то не нашел я в этом API выдачу вариантов поисковых фраз (как из выпадающего списка). Может что-то где-то не там искал?

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо. То что нужно.